# getting 'Cannot read property 'count' of undefined' in an if / else statement (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, this, undefined

i have an array appointment objects of which all each has this key: `"RecurrenceRule"`. Either it is empty (`null`) or it has something of the following:  `"RecurrenceRule": "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5;"`

This is how one element looks like:

```
{ appointmentId: 001239,
    subject: "Something",
    Client: "Bob",
    StartTime: "2020-04-16T11:00:00.000Z",
    EndTime: "2020-04-16T11:30:00.000Z",
    km: 90,
    RecurrenceRule: null,
},
```

What I want to do is iterate through `appointments` by the .reduce() function and if the current element has `"RecurrenceRule": "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5;"`, I want to take the value after 'COUNT=' and assign it to `count` and if `RecurrenceRule` is `null`, I want to assign `1` to `count`, if that makes sense. Below is the method:

```
 export class AppointmentComponent implements OnInit {
appointments;


ngOnInit(){
this.getAppointments();
}


  getAppointments(){
this.appointmentService.getAppointments().subscribe((data : any) => {
  this.appointments= data.appointment;
  this.groupByClient();

});
 };

  groupByClient(){
  var result = [];

  this.appointments.reduce(function (res, value) {
    let diff = dayjs(value.EndTime).diff(dayjs(value.StartTime), "hour",true) % 60;
    if(res[value.RecurrenceRule] !== null) {
      let count =  parseInt(value.RecurrenceRule.split("COUNT=")[1])
    } else {
      let count =  1;
    }
    if (!res[value.Client]) {

      res[value.Client] = {
        km: value.km,
        Client: value.Client,
        count: this.count,
        difference: diff * this.count     
      };
      result.push(res[value.Client]);

    } else {
      res[value.Client].km += value.km;
      res[value.Client].difference += diff;
    }

    return res;
  }, {});
}
}
```

However, when I run this I get the error message: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined`, pointing to the `this.count` lines. What is going wrong here? Is it to do with the nested `this.` ?

If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: Where is all the code you've shown? If there a larger function that it is in? You've started  the `reduce` call with `this.appointments.reduce` so there's no way for us to know what `this` is unless you show how that code is being called.

Comment: this function is being called in the ngOnInit() function, if thats what you mean?

Comment: I don't know if that's what we need or not. Please edit your question and show the complete method that includes the code you've shown. But, based on what you say here, `this` doesn't reference your array of objects, hence your error. If the method is being called from `ngOnInit()`, `this` is probably `window`. You can find out by adding `console.log(this)` right before the `reduce` call to find out what `this` points to.

Comment: If you have declared your array as `appointments`, you can also just remove `this` from `this.appointments.reduce` and make it `appointments.reduct(res, value, arr)` and then replace `this.count` with `arr.count`

Comment: I have updated my question to provide more context as to when the functions are being called. `console.log(this)` just before `this.appointments.reduce` points to the whole component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a variable with `let` it is scoped to the block. In your case `count` doen't exist outside `if(…) {…} else {…}`

You should wirte

```
let count;
if(value.RecurrenceRule !== null) {
      count =  parseInt(value.RecurrenceRule.split("COUNT=")[1])
    } else {
      count =  1;
    }
```

or

```
const count = value.RecurrenceRule ? parseInt(value.RecurrenceRule.split("COUNT=")[1]) : 1;
```

later in your code use `count` instead of `this.count`

Comment: thank you for your solution. While it does get rid of the original error message, it does not apply all the counts properly. What the purpose is, is that of every element in `appointments`, it should multiply the `difference` by either 1 if `RecurrenceRule` is null or by the value that gets taken from the split() function

Comment: instead of `res[value.Client].difference += diff;` shouldn't you have `res[value.Client].difference += diff * count;` ?

Comment: nope still doesnt work. When I add a new appointment with `RecurrenceRule` = 5, it doesnt multiply `difference` with 5 but with 1  :(

Comment: change `res[value.RecurrenceRule]` by `value.RecurrenceRule` (I have edited my answer)